# PeerJS - Manually close the connection between peers

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, peerjs

I use [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/docs/) for my P2P application (a multiplayer game).
Everything is great (connection between peers, sending data), but I can't figure out how to **manually close the connection between peers**.

In docs are functions to "*Close the connection to the server*" or "*Close the connection to the server and terminate all existing connections*" (`peer.disconnect()`,`peer.destroy()`), but I just want to "***terminate existing connections***", not to "*close the connection to the server*".

I know I can handle connections in array and sending/receiving data just for peers with some status (like "connected" or "disconnected"), but other peers can sending data to me for overloading forexample (hackers > ddos...), so basically I want to have opportunity to give something like BAN.

Any ideas (sorry for bad english)?

**SOLVED:**

I must be really blind. There is `DataConnection.close()` function to close the connection between peers.

http://peerjs.com/docs/#dataconnection-close

Comment: Go ahead and post an answer to your own question.

Comment: Can you explain how to disconnect the peer connection. [http://peerjs.com/docs/#dataconnection-close] link is not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `DataConnection.close()` function to close the connection between peers.

http://peerjs.com/docs/#dataconnection-close

Comment: how to get DataConnection?

Comment: i am getting an error `illegal invokation of function`

Comment: @naoval When you use `peer.connect('dest-peer-id')` or the `peer.on 'connection'` event fires, you get a `DataConnection`.